# How to order inline elements in RTL mode?

Tags: html, css

I'm preparing RTL version of the site, and I have a problem with the specific layout:

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
}

.content.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="content">
  <span>3</span> <span>h</span> &nbsp; <span>45</span> <span>min</span>
</h5>
<h5 class="content rtl">
  <span>3</span> <span>h</span> &nbsp; <span>45</span> <span>min</span>
</h5>
```

First h5 tag will display content in the following order: "3h 45min", now I want the second tag to display the following: "min45 h3" which is basically reverse order.

Problem is that I receive the following: "h 45min 3" and I have no idea why.

Do you have any suggestion on how to resolve that layout issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use flex-direction:row-reverse

```css
.content
{
 width: 200px;
}
.content.rtl
{
 display:flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse; 
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="content">
 <span>3</span>
 <span>h</span>
 &nbsp;
 <span>45</span>
 <span>min</span>
</h5>
<h5 class="content rtl">
 <span>3</span>
 <span>h</span>
 &nbsp;
 <span>45</span>
 <span>min</span>
</h5>
 Run code snippetCopy snippet to answerExpand snippet
```

use flex direction

Answer (score 1):

Just add display: inline-block to the spans

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.content.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h5 class="content">
  <span>3</span>
  <span>h</span> &nbsp;
  <span>45</span>
  <span>min</span>
</h5>
<h5 class="content rtl">
  <span>3</span>
  <span>h</span> &nbsp;
  <span>45</span>
  <span>min</span>
</h5>
```

Answer (score 0):

`dir` has an effect on a span, but a span will not be aligned to the right as you expect, only its content.

You will see the effect for `span` if you end it with a dot - the dot will be placed on the left side, and not on the right.

Div is a `display:block` element, meaning it fills the whole width - that's why text can be aligned in it. `Span` is `display:inline`, so it's sitting in the text, similar to a letter (in a simplistic way).

(by the way - it's considered invalid to have a block element inside an inline element)

```
Test right to left, div and span: <br />
<span>(span)  Hello World!</span> <br />
<span dir='rtl'>(span rtl)  Hello World!</span>
<div>(div) Hello World!</div>
<div dir='rtl'>(div rtl) Hello World!</div>
```